# SQL - Compare 2 rows with similar primary key constrains

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a `student`, `course`, and `score_sheet` table. `score_sheet` table has primary key constraints made up of the `student id`, and the `course id`. I want to get a student record where their `course_1` has **higher marks** than `course_2`.

#### Student Table

| student_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s001 | John | 17 |
| s002 | Claire | 18 |
| s003 | Maggie | 19 |

#### Course Table

| course_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| c001 | Math |
| c002 | Art |
| c003 | P.E. |

#### Score Sheet Table

| student_id | course_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s001 | c001 | 78 |
| s001 | c002 | 86 |
| s001 | c003 | 94 |
| s002 | c001 | 90 |
| s002 | c002 | 75 |
| s002 | c003 | 76 |
| s003 | c001 | 65 |
| s003 | c002 | 96 |
| s003 | c003 | 82 |

From the tables above, Claire is the only student satisfying the condition, `course_1` has **higher marks** than `course_2`.

I'm not sure how to write the query into getting such records.

I've only managed to Inner Join the student table with the score_sheet table, and not sure where to go from here.

```
SELECT * FROM student s
INNER JOIN score_sheet sc
    ON s.SNO = sc.SNO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join twice with `score_sheet`, once for each course you want to match.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM student AS s
JOIN score_sheet AS ss1 ON s.student_id = ss1.student_id
JOIN score_sheet AS ss2 ON s.student_id = ss2.student_id AND ss1.score > ss2.score
WHERE ss1.course_id = 'c001' AND ss2.course_id = 'c002'
```

Comment: This seems to make sense, tho somehow when I ran it, it returns 2 Claire and 1 John records. 3 rows in total

Comment: I had a typo in the second join, it should be `ss2.student_id`